# How do I add "via my company name", company logo, and a link to my website to a Facebook share using AddThis buttons and Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, addthis

How do I add "via my company name", company logo, and a link to my website to a Facebook share using AddThis buttons and Javascript

I have a Ruby on Rails web application, and the user interface uses Javascript. Currently, I have working AddThis share buttons. The way my website works is, a user is presented an article from the internet and has the option to share it using the share buttons. The addthis:url is dynamically changed using the Javascript code `addthis.update( 'share', 'url', url )`, where url is the article's url.

I went through some AddThis documentation, and found this:

https://www.addthis.com/help/url-and-title#.T0mk3XMmP6c

When I click on the Facebook share for any of the share buttons on that page, here is a screenshot:

http://imgur.com/d3oIC

Here is how it looks like on my Facebook page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh1F5.jpg

If I could just replace AddThis Sharing with my website's name and link, and keep the article data just like it is in the picture (obviously with the url, title, and description that I provide) that would be ideal. Does anyone know how AddThis was able to do that? Was it using Open Graph tags?

I was unable to copy/paste the code on that page and achieve the same result, as it only used the addthis:url, not the title or description. Here is what that looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwlC4.jpg

There must be something that is not obvious that would allow me to post the way I want to, and I know it is possible, since the AddThis website can do it.

I am not sure if I can use Open Graph tags. The articles on my website are not static urls, so Facebook can't visit a specific page to grab the information it needs. The articles are loaded into the browser with Javascript, so the next one instantly comes up after rating one.

Based on how my website works, and what I need to have working, does anyone think they can help me out? Also, it would be good to know if what I am asking for is absolutely not possible.

```
//If anyone can suggest another tool like AddThis which would work better for the needs and constraints I have, that would be greatly appreciated.
```

I now have Twitter, LinkedIn and email buttons working the way I want, and now all that is left is Facebook. I would really like the Facebook button to work with AddThis.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?  I could really use some similar help you were looking for and was wondering if you'd be willing to follow up on this considering this was posted a year ago...